# Renaming Azure Subscription with REST ends up in BadRequest 400

Tags: azure, powershell, rest

I am getting 400 BadRequest and have no clue why:

```
$RestBody = @{
    "foo" = "bar"
}
$Header = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $CachedAccessToken"
}
$ApiVersion = "api-version=xxx"
$restURI = "https://myURL?$ApiVersion"
    
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Header `
    -Uri $restURI `
    -Method POST ` # Not PUT!
    -ContentType application/json `
    -Body ($RestBody | ConvertTo-Json)
```

Header and Method are correct and double-checked. Even the URL is double-checked.

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an 
    
error: (400) Bad Request.
    
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
    
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()!
    
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
```

Comment: Are you sure `$Header = "Bearer MYSECRET"` shouldn't be `$Header = @{ Authorization = "Bearer MYSECRET"}`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You're right. I've fixed my Post. But it was already correct inside my Code.

Comment: There's nothing else obviously wrong with your code, so it comes down to the specific API in question - if you can't share what it is, then I'm afraid you'll have to just re-read the documentation or contact the vendor :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The API ist still in Preview, but with my local Postman it will work. I've created a Support-Request. Will update the findings here.

Answer (score 0):

**Found the issue!**

Is a Azure-Subscription in "Warn-State", it comes up an "BadRequest". Is the Subscription in "Enable"-State, it results in `200 OK`.

[image]

[image]